# Move object to mouse X

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code for move object to mouse X, but this code does not count the distance(the object follows straight in the mouse) How could I get their kind of controls? Where the player moves positions between offsets instead of lerping to your finger position? Can you please help me?

```
private void HorizontalMovement() 
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) 
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), speed * Time.deltaTime); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your goal a bit further? Currently it is a bit hard to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the movement stop at a certain distance before reaching the exact finger position.

```
// adjust that in the inspector
public float distanceOffset = 0.1f;

private void HorizontalMovement() 
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) 
    {
        // Get the direction from hit object to player
        var direction = (new Vector3(transform.position.x - hit.point.x, 0, 0)).normalized;

        // Add the offset in the direction to the hit position
        var targetPosition = new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z) + direction * distanceOffset;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer!
I want to move object.x witch mouse(the finger controls the object right / left) in this code i will do it but now the object immediately moves to where we click on the screen